# how to build docker image file and push Vsts

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, dockerfile

How to address this error when I push my code on VSTS platform. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I am new to the concept of Docker ,Azure (VSTS).

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["aspnet-core-dotnet-core/aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj", "aspnet-core-dotnet-core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "aspnet-core-dotnet-core/aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/aspnet-core-dotnet-core"
RUN dotnet build "aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnet-core-dotnet-core.dll"]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a path wrong  in your first COPY statement. Do you have your source code in a subdirectory such as `src` in source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the DockerFile and error message, it failed to copy **aspnet-core-dotnet-core/aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj** file.

You need to specify DockerFile's **parent folder** path as the build context (Uncheck **Use Default Build Context** option and specify Build Context), then it can find the **aspnet-core-dotnet-core/aspnet-core-dotnet-core.csproj** file